# Pyenv - Missing the GNU readline lib warning ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, ubuntu-18.04

How can I resolve this warning while installing specific versions of python

Output (minimal):

```
Installing Python-3.5.5...
python-build: use readline from homebrew
WARNING: The Python readline extension was not compiled. Missing the GNU readline lib?
```

Things I have tried:

- I have uninstalled and reinstall `libreadline-dev` and it's alternative `libedit-dev`, as seen [here](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki/common-build-problems)
- also installed and updated homebrew, then installed `readline` and `xz` as dictated in the above link also.

Answer (score 8):

`sudo apt install libreadline-dev`

This is specific for the `readline`. But if you're install PyEnv, you can refer to this [link](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/1508#issuecomment-572617960) too.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be some mismatch between the readline brew installs and what pyenv expects. The readline from apt seems to do its job, so just uninstall readline from brew. NB. readline is a dependency for pyenv, but it seems it can be removed safely.

```
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies readline
```

** The typo in the command has been fixed.